# Pandas groupby Series with DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group a Series by a DataFrame and then perform a reduction as in the following example:

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [2]: df = DataFrame([['Alice', 'F', 100, 1],
                        ['Alice', 'F', 100, 3],
                        ['Drew', 'F', 100, 4],
                        ['Drew', 'M', 100, 5],
                        ['Drew', 'M', 200, 5]],
                       columns=['name', 'sex', 'amount', 'id'])

In [3]: df['amount'].groupby(df[['name', 'sex']]).count()
```

Unfortunately this raises the following TypeError which has me stumped

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I know that I can use the column names directly but I my actual computation needs to be a bit more general than that and thought that this would be doable.  What is going on here?  What is the proper way to group-and-reduce a series by an arbitrary DataFrame?  Or alternatively, does such a way not exist?

Comment: What's the connection between the series and df?

Comment: I think his Series is `df['amount']`.

@Mrocklin, just to check, `df.groupby(['name', 'sex'])['amount'].count()` doesn't quite work for you, right? `groupby` also allows grouping by a function or mapping (like a Series), which is why its giving you the not callable error.

Comment: That does to help explain the error, thanks @TomAugspurger .  In this case what you suggest would work fine.  My full problem is general and the grouping dataframe might be more complex than the example here.

Comment: Ok. If you find a small example that will demonstrate that, hopefully we can help. (PS, thanks for PyToolz!)

Comment: This may not be general (or efficient) enough but one thing you can do as a work around is pass a `MultiIndex` to the `groupby`. Don't set those columns as the index but rather create a separate `MultiIndex` object and then pass it to the `groupby`. So something like:  `idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(df.name,df.sex), names=['name', 'sex'])` and then pass `idx` to the `groupby`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to turn the Series into a DataFrame, join to the grouper DataFrame, then groupby on the columns of the grouper then reselect out the columns of the grouped.  I.e.

```
# Example inputs
pregrouped = df['amount']
grouper = df[['name', 'sex']]

# General computation
pregrouped = DataFrame(pregrouped)
grouper = DataFrame(grouper) 

full = grouper.join(pregrouped)
groups = full.groupby(list(grouper.columns))[list(pregrouped.columns)]
result = groups.some_reduction()[list(pregrouped.columns)].reset_index()
```

Is anything here very wasteful? This approach runs at about the speed of the normal idiomatic computation that's available in common cases.